# Raspberry pi malformed display

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have 2 raspberry pis, suddenly yesterday one of them started using the full screen on reboot, now the relations between height and width are wrong. I copied the /boot/config.txt file from the working pi to the other, still same problem! What is going on?!? Please Help!

Comment: what is the display? TV? Monitor? What interface is the connection?

Comment: @jhnc I use a Computer monitor connected via HDMI.

Comment: what do you see if you plug the working pi into this monitor?

Comment: I see a small black border on the borders

Comment: Everything like after fresh install

Comment: I have installed a lot of RPIs but this has never happened to me

Comment: I mean does the working pi show the correct aspect ratio with this monitor?

Comment: You may get better response on the raspberry pi site. A related question there is: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24343